# Flie Upload Clearing File input Value Individually

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I have file upload method.Its have add,remove,clear fields.Add and remove working perfectly. In clear method I have two file input values.when I click the clear both input values are cleared. I want clear the particular file input value only.

How to resolve this issue

```js
$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {

   var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);    

   $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {    
    $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();   
   });

   $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
    if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
     $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
   }); 

   $('.multi-field .clear-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
    //if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
    if(navigator.userAgent.toUpperCase().indexOf('MSIE') >= 0){
     $("input[type='file']").replaceWith($("input[type='file']").clone(true));
    } else {
     $("input[type='file']").val('');
    }
   }); 
});
```

```html
<div class="multi-field-wrapper">
  <div class="multi-fields">
    <div class="multi-field">
      <input type="file" value="choose files" id="attach" name="attach[]" onchange="check_file_sizes();"/>
      <button type="button" class="remove-field">Remove</button>
      <button type="button" class="clear-field">Clear</button>
      <!--<button type="button" id="clear" >Clear</button> -->                            
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="add-field">Add field</button>                          
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/techpalani/987ry6nn/1/

Comment: you provided wrong link to JsFiddle. Correct it please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with your selector. Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/987ry6nn/6/). You should change your `clear` function as follows:

```
$('.multi-field .clear-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
        //if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
        if(navigator.userAgent.toUpperCase().indexOf('MSIE') >= 0){
          $(this).closest('.multi-field').find("input[type='file']").replaceWith($("input[type='file']").clone(true));
        } else {
          $(this).closest('.multi-field').find("input[type='file']").val('');
        }
});
```